# How to define an interface that has any number of properties of a certain type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to define an interface that has arbitrary properties whose type is always the same. E.g.

```
type Reducer<S, P> = (state: S, payload: P) => S

interface Reducers {
  [name: string]: Reducer
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
interface MyState {
  foo?: string
  bar?: string
}

const reducers: Reducers = {
  r1: (state: MyState, payload: string) => {
    return {foo: payload}
  }
}
```

However I cannot get this to compile. The compiler error is:

> Error TS2314: Generic type 'Reducer' requires 2 type argument(s).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `r1`, a literal property name or a variable? And what is your compiler error?

Comment: `r1` is just a property name. I want an object that implements `Reducers` to be able to have any number of properties of type `Reducer`. Compiler error added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to forward your generic arguments to your `Reducers` interface:

```
interface Reducers<S, P> {
  [name: string]: Reducer<S, P>
}

const reducers: Reducers<MyState, string> = {
  r1: (state: MyState, payload: string) => {
    return {foo: payload}
  }
}
```

In case the compiler does not allow you to define your `Reducer` method inline (I had some trouble with this in the past), you can define the value externally:

```
const r1Reducer: Reducer<MyState, string> = (state: MyState, payload: string) => {
    return {foo: payload}
}

const reducers: Reducers<MyState, string> = {
  r1: r1Reducer;
}
```

Comment: That looks good. The problem I get now is if I try to access one of the properties (e.g. `reducers.r1({foo: 1}, 2)`) I get the error `Property 'r1' does not exist on type 'Reducers<MyState, string>'`

Comment: that's because the Reducers interface is an indexed interface and the compiler doesn't know the property names upfront. You should do reducers['r1'] instead.

Comment: ah ok, thanks. So the other option is either to explicitly define the interface properties. I'm wondering if my approach is OK, but I want to avoid defining specific types for every instance of a 'reducers' I create.

Comment: @toskv: Hence my comment in the question whether r1 is a literal name. ;)

Comment: @harryg you can also opt for not giving the reducers constant a type. That way the compiler will create an anonymous type for it from whatever it contains. It allow for a lot more freedom but it's a lot easier to break things that way as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some generics type notations in your code.

```js
type Reducer<S, P> = (state: S, payload: P) => S

interface Reducers<S, P> {
  [name: string]: Reducer<S, P>
}

interface MyState {
  foo?: string
  bar?: string
}

const reducers: Reducers<MyState, string> = {
  r1: (state: MyState, payload: string) => {
    return { foo: payload }
  }
}
```

Without them the compiler can't determine the correct type of S and P generic types.